# how to fix applet parameter

Tags: java, applet

my program works fine only if i move "setBackground(color);" to "init()". how to fix it ?
my task is to Pass in three integers corresponding to an RGB value and use the appropriate Color constructor to set the background color.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AnAppletSubclass2b extends Applet {
int r;
int g;
int b;
Color color;
public void init()
{

    String parmStringRED =  getParameter("red");
     r = Integer.parseInt(parmStringRED);
    String parmStringGREEN =  getParameter("green");
     g = Integer.parseInt(parmStringGREEN);
    String parmStringBLUE =  getParameter("blue");
     b = Integer.parseInt(parmStringBLUE);
    Color color = new Color (r,g,b);

    System.out.println("The parameter are: red: " + parmStringRED + ", green: " + parmStringGREEN + ", blue: " + parmStringBLUE);


}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    setBackground(color);
    System.out.println("In paint: n = " + n);
    n++;
}

int n;
}
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> AnApplet With Parms </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<p>Here is the output of my  Program:</p>   
<APPLET CODE="AnAppletSubclass2b.class" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=100>
<PARAM name="red" value="25" >      
<PARAM name="green" value="250">
<PARAM name="blue" value="120">
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have a color variable defined as a field and another one defined as a local. Change

```
Color color = new Color (r,g,b);
```

to

```
color = new Color (r,g,b);
```